# Copying a specific word of webpage to excel using vbs

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I want to copy the particular text "110001" present in a webpage to a sheet in my Excel file. Please tell me how I can do this through vbscript. Below is the relevant line of source code which I want to copy.

```
<h1 id="h1">110001</h1>
```

Below is the code that I am using. The problem in this code is that it is not copying anything from the webpage. Also, it is giving Run time error 1004 on the 3rd last line - Range("A1").Select

```
Private Sub blahblah_Click()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://someWebsite"
    Do While ie.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
Set y = ie.Document.getelementbyid("h1")
ie.ExecWB 12, 2
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can copy-pasting be avoided? Try this one instead.

```
Private Sub blahblah_Click()
Dim ie As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WB = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://someWebsite"
    Do While ie.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
y = ie.Document.getelementbyid("h1").innerHTML
WS.Range("A1").Value = y
End Sub
```

Basically, you need the `innerHTML` part, as this is the needed control to get the value inside the HTML tags with that element ID.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

y = ie.document.getElementById("ad-space.holdings").innerHTML

the above code showing me an error or err.number = 424..

Let me know do I need to select anything from reference in VBA?

Comment: I think this should be a comment, for starters but it's ok since you don't have the permission to comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub blahblah_Click()
Dim ie As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WB = Workbooks.Add
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://etfdb.com/etf/EEM/#holdings"
    Do While ie.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
y = ie.document.getElementById("ad-space.holdings").innerHTML
WS.Range("A1").Value = y
End Sub
```